# Read internal and external files with node-webkit

Tags: javascript, require, readfile, node-webkit

I use nw.js and zip following files into a `package.nw` file:

```
js/main.js
ui/widget.html
index.html
package.json
```

Additionally, I have an external file that comes along the package, so I have these files in the end:

```
package.nw
settings.json
```

The `package.json` is configured to start with `index.html`. There, I link `js/main.js` with a script tag:

```
<!-- inside index.html -->
<script src="js/main.js"></script>
```

The `index.html` and code in `js/main.js` work perfectly, I've tested them.

The two *interesting* files (`ui/widget.html` and `settings.json` contain perfect HTML and JSON respectively).

Inside `js/main.js` I want to load both, `ui/widget.html` and `settings.json`. To do so, I have tried:

```
// inside js/main.js
var fs, w1, w2;

fs = require("fs");
w1 = fs.readFileSync("ui/widget.html");
w2 = require("ui/widget.html");
```

The results are:

> w1: "" (empty string)
>
> w2: ERROR (Unexpected token "<")

When I change the filename I get for `w1` the error `ENOENT` (no such file or directory). So I can tell that with the correct filename, for `w1` **the entry is actually found in the package** (no `ENOENT`) but the content is somehow not loaded into the string.

The error for `w2` is probably caused by an implicit `JSON.parse()` or `eval()`, which is understandable/acceptable. It was more a desperate attempt than something I expected to work.

So, I have tried for hours but I cannot read that file.

For the second case (the external `settings.json`) I have tried this:

```
// inside js/main.js
var fs, s1, s2, s3;

fs = require("fs");
s1 = fs.readFileSync("settings.json");
s2 = require("settings.json");
s3 = require("settings");
```

For `s1` I get:

```
"" (empty string)
```

For `s2`:

```
Error: Cannot find module 'settings'
```

For `s3`:

```
Error: Cannot find module 'settings.json'
```

It looks like there's no way I can open that file, either. I also tried changing directories before launching `nw`, but to no avail.

I've exhausted all paths, options, attempts and manuals/tutorials/SO questions. What a I doing wrong in those two different cases?

---

I've rewritten a clean test-case but the problem is exactly the same. I omit `fs` in `node_modules`, installed with *npm*.

This is source from another example with the very same problem.

Content of `package.json`:

```
{
  "name": "test",
  "main": "index.html",
  "window": {
    "toolbar": false,
    "width": 800,
    "height": 480
  }
}
```

Content of `index.html`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
  <head>
    <script src="main.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
  </body>
</html>
```

Content of `main.js`:

```
"use strict";

window.onload = function () {
  var fs, html;

  fs = require("fs");

  try {
    html = fs.readFileSync("./test.html");
    console.log(html);          // empty string
  } catch(ex) {
    console.log(ex.message);    // unreached
  }

  try {
    html = require("./test.html");
    console.log(html);          // unreached
  } catch(ex) {
    console.log(ex.message);    // error
  }
};
```

Content of `test.html`:

```
<div id="widget_message">
  @message
</div>
```

Comment: According to the documentation, `fs.readFileSync()` returns a string if and only if the second parameter, `encoding`, is specified. Otherwise it returns a buffer. Have you tried with `fs.readFileSync("settings.json", "utf8");` ?

Comment: That's what I was missing! Thanks. If you reply in an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the documentation, `fs.readFileSync()` returns a `String` if and only if the second parameter, `encoding`, is specified. Otherwise it returns a buffer.

So `fs.readFileSync("settings.json", "utf8")` should do the trick.